# Why does a synchronous .NET Core CAP subscriber cause an exception and for the catch block not to be hit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

Note: This poor behavior only occurs if I make the CAP subscriber method synchronous. If it's async (`async Task` in the method signature), no exception occurs.

When using .NET Core CAP to get messages off a RabbitMQ, an exception occurs in our repo metho, and the catch block of the event handler never gets hit.

```
    [CapSubscribe(nameof(IntegrationEvent))]
    public void Handle(IntegrationEvent integrationEvent)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("some message");

        // Wrap in try/catch, otherwise retries will kick in. If the recalc fails, it's usually due to bad data.
        try
        {
            _recalcProcessor.RecalcByPolicyAsync(integrationEvent.RecalculationDate, integrationEvent.EmployeeId,
                integrationEvent.PolicyId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // THIS DOESN'T GET HIT UNLESS THE METHOD IS ASYNC
            _logger.LogError(ex, "some message");
        }
    }
```

And here is RecalcByPolicyAsync, that is basically just a pass-through to the repo method:

```
    public async Task RecalcByPolicyAsync(DateTime recalcFromDate, long employeeId, long policyId)
    {
        List<AccrualGroup> groups;
        using (var uow = _uowFactory.Create(false))
        {
            groups = await uow.AccrualRepo.GetAccrualGroupsByPolicyIdAsync(policyId);
        }
    }
```

This is the line that produces the exception in the repo method. Remember, this exception doesn't happen if the event handler is async.

```
_ = await Connection.QueryAsync<DomainEntity1, DomainEntity2>(...
```

This is the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call FieldCount
> when reader is closed.' This exception was originally thrown at this
> call stack: [External Code]
> Xxx.Shared.Infrastructure.Repositories.AccrualRepo.GetAccrualGroupsByPolicyIdAsync(long)
> in AccrualRepo.cs

When the exception occurs, no `catch` blocks are hit on the way back up the call stack. The process seems to end and that's it. Why would that happen just by making the handler synchronous?

If the handler is async, like this, things just work:

```
public async Task Handle(RecalcEmployeeAccrualPolicyIntegrationEvent integrationEvent)
```

However, we don't want to process our event messages async because they happen all at once and we exhaust our SQL connections.

Comment: If you don't *await* an asynchronous operation, execution proceeds and the method terminates. The best option is to make `Handle` an asynchronous method by adding `async Task` to the signature and use `await _recalsProcessor...`. To avoid blocking, the entire call chain should be async all the way to the top. The other option is to *block* by calling `.Wait()` on the async method

Comment: To add on @PanagiotisKanavos comment,  If you're trying to run a large processing task, but you still want to return first you should be using a HostedService which is .net's implementation of Background services, which will assure the task will run to completition

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this may work. Testing now. Fix: `_recalcProcessor.RecalcByPolicyAsync(...).Wait();`